# How to format a table with counts, percents and marginal totals

Tags: r

I often need to create a formatted table with counts, percents and marginal totals. For example I might have data with three classes and two categories. I want to make a table with a row for each class, containing within-class counts and percents for each category and the total count for the category. Finally, a total row at the bottom totals categories, shows categories as percent of total, and an overall total.

The code is always ugly :-) and I would love to find a better way. Here is a very simple example; often it is much more complex than this.

```
=====  ===  =======  ===  ======  =====
Class  Yes  Yes pct   No  No pct  Total
=====  ===  =======  ===  ======  =====
one     35      65%   19     35%     54
two     21      70%    9     30%     30
three    9      56%    7     44%     16
Total   65      65%   35     35%    100
=====  ===  =======  ===  ======  =====
```

I know about `addmargins` (doesn't work on data.frame), `prop.table` (gives a separate table of proportions), `descr::CrossTable` (puts values in cells, not spread across the row). Any suggestions for how to clean this up are welcome.

Here is the code to create the above table:

```
library(formattable) # For nice percents
library(tidyverse)

# Make up some data. Three classes with two categories within each class
# Order of cls is important so it is a factor
d = tibble(cls=sample(c('one', 'two', 'three'), 100, 
                      replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)),
           conf=sample(c('yes', 'no'), 100, 
                       replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.6, 0.4))) %>% 
  mutate(cls = factor(cls, levels=c('one', 'two', 'three', 'Total')))

# Tabulate by cls and conf
d2 = d %>% group_by(cls, conf) %>% 
  summarise(n=n()) %>% # Total per cls x conf
  spread(conf, n)  # Spread to one row per cls

# Add a total row. Do this before calculating percents so we don't total
# the within-row percents. This is really ugly
d2 = d2 %>% bind_rows(as_data_frame(t(c(cls=NA, colSums(d2[,-1])))))
d2$cls[nrow(d2)] = 'Total'

d2 = d2 %>% mutate(total=no+yes, # Make percents and row totals
         no_pct=percent(no/total, 0),
         yes_pct=percent(yes/total, 0)) %>% 
  select(Class=cls, Yes=yes, `Yes pct`=yes_pct, # Reorder and rename columns
         No=no, `No pct`=no_pct, Total=total)

formattable(d2) # Yay! Nice table.
knitr::kable(d2, format='rst') # For pasting above
```

Comment: Have you tried the package `janitor` ? It has the functions `add_totals_col` and `add_totals_row` that might simplify your task at hand.

Comment: I have actually just spent a few days working on some of these and  in the end I just found the tidyverse not so useful because of n() not being a real function. I basically ended up making my own crosstab (and for one variable frequencytable) classes with their own print functions.  It ended up being easier than messing around.

Comment: More or less https://gist.github.com/elinw/fc120b0e1ca9f3037f819c4e187d1986

Comment: @JuanBosco Thanks for the tip, I did not know about `janitor`. It is close...I would rather have the numbers and percents in separate columns, with both row and column totals. `janitor::add_totals_row` is a cleaner version of my code for the same task. Lots of good stuff there.

To some extent I am interested in techniques as well as finished solutions; most of my actual tables are more complex than my example so I may always be writing custom code.

Comment: @Elin That only gets me part way, I guess I would need the print function as well, or something that assembles the parts.

Comment: I added the print file ... it's really not as thought out because it's basically a modification of the core print file, but changing some options and adding a couple of things.  I am thinking it would not be too bad to interleave the frequencies and the percents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below is still somewhat involved (perhaps it can be simplified further), but it seems more intuitive to me and takes advantage of `tidyverse` functionality. I've included comments to explain what the code is doing at each stage.

```
# Tabulate by cls and conf
d2 = d %>% group_by(cls, conf) %>%             
  tally %>% 
  # Add a row with column totals (group only by conf, instead of by cls and conf)
  bind_rows(d %>% group_by(conf) %>%           
      tally %>%
      mutate(cls="Total")) %>%
  # Add percent column by taking advantage of long format and pre-existing grouping
  mutate(pct = round(n/sum(n)*100)) %>%
  # Now spread to wide format       
  gather(key, value, n, pct, -cls, -conf) %>%  
  unite(conf_key, conf, key) %>%
  spread(conf_key, value) %>%
  # Add percent symbols
  mutate_at(vars(matches("pct")), funs(paste0(.,"%"))) %>%
  # Get cls values in the right order and add row totals
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(cls = factor(cls, levels=c("one","two","three","Total")),
         Total = no_n + yes_n) %>%
  arrange(cls) %>%
  select(Class=cls, Yes=yes_n, `Yes pct`=yes_pct, No=no_n, `No pct`=no_pct, Total)
```

> ```
>    Class   Yes `Yes pct`    No `No pct` Total
> 1    one    32       73%    12      27%    44
> 2    two    21       52%    19      48%    40
> 3  three    10       62%     6      38%    16
> 4  Total    63       63%    37      37%   100
> ```

Comment: Thank you, that is very clean!